# JS post request with fetch doesn't work with instagram api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to make a post request to an endpoint of the instagram api (https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token).

Here is what I'm doing:

```js
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    client_id: APP_ID,
    client_secret: APP_SECRET,
    code,
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI
  })
};

fetch("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", requestOptions)
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then(r => console.log(r))
```

APP_ID, APP_SECRET & REDIRECT_URI aren't null (I can see them in the request payload)

[image: Request payload]

However I still get a 400 error saying: "Missing required field client_id"

Any thoughts on this? Thanks

Comment: try with postman, still getting the error?

Comment: You need `header: { "Content-type": "application/json" }` to post JSON but I think the [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/oauth-access-token/) is expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `headers` but in any case, it's not applicable for what you're trying to do